# Problem with getting a table from a website with pandas

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a table from a website with `pd.read_html`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/financial-ratios?freq=Q'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
```

however no table is found:

`ValueError: No tables found`

Is there a quick remedy here, I'm not experienced with web scraping.

Thank you

Comment: It will not find a table, cause there is no html table - Content is generated dynamically by javascript - You can try to extract data from JavaScript or use Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** *As mentioned in my comment there is no HTML table and content is generated dynamically by JavaScript - Alternatives are extract info from JavaScript or using Selenium*

Another alternative, if you like to go with `pandas.read_html()`, is to pick the specific ressources for historic metrics stored in tables and process it in the way you like:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/'
metrics = ['current-ratio','ebit-margin']

for m in metrics:
    html = requests.get(url+m).content
    print(pd.read_html(html)[0]) #or process/store for your needs
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't return the table I'm looking for.

Comment: That is correct but an alternative to get your goal if you do not want to  use selenium or extract the information from JavaScript - " quick remedy"